# How to extract a specific value from JSON file?

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to extract a specific value from JSON file.

the key value is: "info": "this is an example" (The key is unique)

I want to extract only the value: "this is an example"

My code:

```
cat 9.json | jq '.info'
```

result:

```
null
```

JSON file example:

```
{
    "Event": {
        "id": "13",
        "orgc_id": "1",
        "org_id": "1",
        "date": "2019-01-09",
        "threat_level_id": "3",
        "info": "test9",
        "published": false,
        "uuid": "5c35d180",
        "attribute_count": "2",
        "analysis": "0",
        "timestamp": "1547044733",
        "distribution": "1",
        "proposal_email_lock": false,
        "locked": false,
        "publish_timestamp": "1547034089",
        "sharing_group_id": "0",
        "disable_correlation": false,
        "extends_uuid": "",
        "event_creator_email": "o@cyhgfnt.com",
        "Org": {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Cygfdgfdnt",
            "uuid": "5b9f938d-e3a0-4ecb-83b3-0bdeac1b41bc"
        },
        "Orgc": {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Cyhgfgft",
            "uuid": "5b9f938d-e3a0-4ecb-83b3-0bdeac1b41bc"
        },
        "Attribute": [{
            "id": "292630",
            "type": "domain",
            "category": "Network activity",
            "to_ids": true,
            "uuid": "5c35dd94-cccc-4086-b386-682823717aa5",
            "event_id": "1357",
            "distribution": "5",
            "timestamp": "1547034584",
            "comment": "This is a comment",
            "sharing_group_id": "0",
            "deleted": false,
            "disable_correlation": false,
            "object_id": "0",
            "object_relation": null,
            "value": "dodskj.com",
            "Galaxy": [],
            "ShadowAttribute": [],
            "Tag": [{
                "id": "223",
                "name": "kill-chain:Exploitation",
                "colour": "#a80079",
                "exportable": true,
                "user_id": "0",
                "hide_tag": false,
                "numerical_value": null
            }]
        }, {
            "id": "292631",
            "type": "ip-dst",
            "category": "Network activity",
            "to_ids": true,
            "uuid": "5c35dd94-fe90-4ef6-b3a9-682823717aa5",
            "event_id": "1357",
            "distribution": "5",
            "timestamp": "1547044733",
            "comment": "comment example",
            "sharing_group_id": "0",
            "deleted": false,
            "disable_correlation": false,
            "object_id": "0",
            "object_relation": null,
            "value": "8.8.6.6",
            "Galaxy": [],
            "ShadowAttribute": [],
            "Tag": [{
                "id": "247",
                "name": "maec-malware-capabilities:maec-malware-capability=\"anti-removal\"",
                "colour": "#3f0004",
                "exportable": true,
                "user_id": "0",
                "hide_tag": false,
                "numerical_value": null
            }, {
                "id": "465",
                "name": "osint:lifetime=\"perpetual\"",
                "colour": "#006ebe",
                "exportable": true,
                "user_id": "0",
                "hide_tag": false,
                "numerical_value": null
            }]
        }],
        "ShadowAttribute": [],
        "RelatedEvent": [],
        "Galaxy": [{
            "id": "3",
            "uuid": "698774c7-8022-42c4-917f-8d6e4f06ada3",
            "name": "Threat Actor",
            "type": "threat-actor",
            "description": "Threat actors are characteristics of malicious actors (or adversaries) representing a cyber attack threat including presumed intent and historically observed behaviour.",
            "version": "3",
            "icon": "user-secret",
            "namespace": "misp",
            "GalaxyCluster": [{
                "id": "6397",
                "collection_uuid": "7cdff317-a673-4474-84ec-4f1754947823",
                "type": "threat-actor",
                "value": "Sofacy",
                "tag_name": "misp-galaxy:threat-actor=\"Sofacy\"",
                "description": "The Sofacy Group (also known as APT28, Pawn Storm, Fancy Bear and Sednit) is a cyber espionage group believed to have ties to the Russian government. Likely operating since 2007, the group is known to target government, military, and security organizations. It has been characterized as an advanced persistent threat.",
                "galaxy_id": "3",
                "source": "MISP Project",
                "authors": ["Alexandre Dulaunoy", "Florian Roth", "Thomas Schreck", "Timo Steffens", "Various"],
                "version": "82",
                "uuid": "5b4ee3ea-eee3-4c8e-8323-85ae32658754",
                "tag_id": "608",
                "meta": {
                    "cfr-suspected-state-sponsor": ["Russian Federation"],
                    "cfr-suspected-victims": ["Georgia", "France", "Jordan", "United States", "Hungary", "World Anti-Doping Agency", "Armenia", "Tajikistan", "Japan", "NATO", "Ukraine", "Belgium", "Pakistan", "Asia Pacific Economic Cooperation", "International Association of Athletics Federations", "Turkey", "Mongolia", "OSCE", "United Kingdom", "Germany", "Poland", "European Commission", "Afghanistan", "Kazakhstan", "China"],
                    "cfr-target-category": ["Government", "Military"],
                    "cfr-type-of-incident": ["Espionage"],
                    "country": ["RU"],
                    "refs": ["https:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Sofacy_Group", "https:\/\/aptnotes.malwareconfig.com\/web\/viewer.html?file=..\/APTnotes\/2014\/apt28.pdf", "http:\/\/www.trendmicro.com\/cloud-content\/us\/pdfs\/security-intelligence\/white-papers\/wp-operation-pawn-storm.pdf", "https:\/\/www2.fireeye.com\/rs\/848-DID-242\/images\/wp-mandiant-matryoshka-mining.pdf", "https:\/\/www.crowdstrike.com\/blog\/bears-midst-intrusion-democratic-national-committee\/", "http:\/\/researchcenter.paloaltonetworks.com\/2016\/06\/unit42-new-sofacy-attacks-against-us-government-agency\/", "https:\/\/www.cfr.org\/interactive\/cyber-operations\/apt-28", "https:\/\/blogs.microsoft.com\/on-the-issues\/2018\/08\/20\/we-are-taking-new-steps-against-broadening-threats-to-democracy\/", "https:\/\/www.bleepingcomputer.com\/news\/security\/microsoft-disrupts-apt28-hacking-campaign-aimed-at-us-midterm-elections\/", "https:\/\/www.bleepingcomputer.com\/news\/security\/apt28-uses-lojax-first-uefi-rootkit-seen-in-the-wild\/"],
                    "synonyms": ["APT 28", "APT28", "Pawn Storm", "PawnStorm", "Fancy Bear", "Sednit", "TsarTeam", "Tsar Team", "TG-4127", "Group-4127", "STRONTIUM", "TAG_0700", "Swallowtail", "IRON TWILIGHT", "Group 74"]
                }
            }]
        }],
        "Object": [],
        "Tag": [{
            "id": "608",
            "name": "misp-galaxy:threat-actor=\"Sofacy\"",
            "colour": "#12e000",
            "exportable": true,
            "user_id": "0",
            "hide_tag": false,
            "numerical_value": null
        }, {
            "id": "118",
            "name": "gdpr:special-categories=\"health\"",
            "colour": "#3ce600",
            "exportable": true,
            "user_id": "0",
            "hide_tag": false,
            "numerical_value": null
        }]
    }
 }
```

Comment: Use example["Event"]["info"]

Comment: The sample JSON does not match the problem description. Please fix one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are trying to get the `.info` field inside `.Event` which should have been written as below. Use `-r` for without quotes

```
jq '.Event.info'
```