# how to extract a value from a json format

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I need to extract the email from an intricate 'dict' (I am new to sql)

I have seen several previous posts on the same topic (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54125850/how-to-extract-a-specific-value-from-json-file)) however, none seem to work on my data

```sql
select au.details
from table_au au
```

result:

```
{
   "id":3526,
   "contacts":[
      {
         "contactType":"EMAIL",
         "value":"name@email.be",
         "private":false
      },
      {
         "contactType":"PHONE",
         "phoneType":"PHONE",
         "value":"025/6251111",
         "private":false
      }
   ]
}
```

I need:

```
name@email.be
```

Comment: Tag the DBMS this is for.

Comment: can tag specific DBMS name on which you are working, not only 'database' tag

Answer (score 1):

```
select d.value -> 0 -> 'value' as Email 
from json_each('{"id":3526,"contacts":[{"contactType":"EMAIL","value":"name@email.be","private":false},{"contactType":"PHONE","phoneType":"PHONE","value":"025/6251111","private":false}]}') d 
where d.key::text = 'contacts'
```

Output:

```
|   | email         |
 -------------------
|1  |"name@email.be"|
```

You can run it here: https://rextester.com/VHWRQ89385